# Big-O running time for functions

Tags: math, big-o

Find the big-O running time for each of these functions:

1. `T(n) = T(n - 2) + n²`
   Our Answers: `n²`, `n³`
2. `T(n) = 3T(n/2) + n`
   Our Answers: `O(n log n)`, `O(nlog₂3)`
3. `T(n) = 2T(n/3) + n`
   Our Answers: `O(n log base 3 of n)`, `O(n)`
4. `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^3`
   Our Answers: `O(n³ log₂n)`, `O(n³)`

So we're having trouble deciding on the right answers for each of the questions.

We all got different results and would like an outside opinion on what the running time would be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Functions (in the mathematical sense) don't have running times.  Perhaps you want to know what the least big-O class is that contains each of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

**A bit of clarification**:
The functions in the questions appear to be ***running time functions*** as hinted by their `T()` name and their `n` parameter.  A more subtle hint is the fact that they are all recursive and recursive functions are, alas, a common occurrence when one produces a function to describe the running time of an algorithm (even when the algorithm itself isn't formally using recursion).  Indeed, recursive formulas are a rather inconvenient form and that is why we use the ***Big O notation*** to better summarize the behavior of an algorithm.

A running time function is a parametrized mathematical expression which allows computing a [sometimes approximate] relative value for the running time of an algorithm, given specific value(s) for the parameter(s).  As is the case here, running time functions typically have a single parameter, often named `n`, and corresponding to the total number of *items* the algorithm is expected to work on/with (for e.g. with a search algorithm it could be the total number of records in a database, with a sort algorithm it could be the number of entries in the unsorted list and for a path finding algorithm, the number of nodes in the graph....). In some cases a running time function may have multiple arguments, for example, the performance of an algorithm performing some transformation on a graph may be bound to both the total number of nodes *and* the total number of vertices or the average number of connections between two nodes, etc.

The **task at hand** (for what appears to be homework, hence my partial answer), is therefore to find a [**Big O**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) expression that qualifies the upper bound limit of each of running time functions, *whatever the underlying algorithm they may correspond to*.  The task is *not* that of finding and qualifying an algorithm to produce the results of the functions (this second possibility is also a very common type of exercise in Algorithm classes of a CS cursus but is apparently not what is required here.)

The problem is therefore more one of mathematics than of Computer Science per se.
  Basically one needs to find the limit (or an approximation thereof) of each of these functions as n approaches infinity.
This [**note from Prof. Jeff Erikson**](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/99-recurrences.pdf) at University of Illinois Urbana Champaign provides **a good intro to solving recurrences**.
Although there are a few shortcuts to solving recurrences, particularly if one has with a good command of calculus, a generic approach is to guess the answer and then to prove it by induction.  Tools like Excel, a few snippets in a programming languages such as Python or also MATLAB or [Sage](http://www.sagenb.org/) can be useful to produce tables of the first few hundred values (or beyond) along with values such as n^2, n^3, n! as well as ratios of the terms of the function; these tables often provide enough insight into the function to find the closed form of the function.

A few **hints regarding the answers listed in the question**:
Function a)
     `O(n^2)` is for sure wrong:
         a quick inspection of the first few values in the sequence show that n^2 is increasingly much smaller than T(n)
    `O(n^3)` on the other hand appears to be systematically bigger than `T(n)` as n grows towards big numbers.   A closer look shows that `O(n^3)` is effectively the *order* of the Big O notation for this function, but that `O(n^3 / 6)` is a more precise notation which systematically exceed the value of T(n) [for bigger values of n, and/or as n tends towards infinity] but only by a minute fraction compared with the coarser `n^3` estimate.
One can confirm that  `O(n^3 / 6)` is it, by induction:

```
T(n) = T(n-2) + n^2  // (1) by definition
T(n) = n^3 / 6       // (2) our "guess"
T(n) = ((n - 2)^3 / 6) + n^2   // by substitution of T(n-2) by the (2) expression
     = (n^3 - 2n^2 -4n^2 -8n + 4n - 8) / 6  + 6n^2 / 6
     = (n^3 - 4n -8) / 6
     = n^3/6 - 2n/3 - 4/3
     ~=  n^3/6      // as n grows towards infinity, the 2n/3 and 4/3 factors
                    // become relatively insignificant, leaving us with the
                    // (n^3 / 6) limit expression, QED
```